# Change NaN, INF values to 0 in php Array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

So I have an array in Php where I have the following values respectively.

```
$arr = [1,2,0,0,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,5,7,6,4,7,4,6,4,7,1,15,35];
```

So when I am applying the growth rate formula in this. Some of the values showing NaN and INF. I Know it's happening because of the `0` I put in the array.

So What I need is to replace the NaN, INF values with 0 or something so the values not get skipped.

I tried in many ways. but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code :
$growthrate = [];

```
$arr = [1,2,0,0,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,5,7,6,4,7,4,6,4,7,1,15,35];

for($i=1;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
 
 $growthrate[] = $arr[$i]/$arr[$i-1];
 
 error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

}

print_r($growthrate);
```

Here you can see the output I am getting :

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 0 [2] => NAN [3] => INF [4] => 1.2 [5] => 1.1666666666667 [6] => 1.1428571428571 [7] => 1.125 [8] => 1.1111111111111 [9] => 0.7 [10] => 0.71428571428571 [11] => 1.4 [12] => 0.85714285714286 [13] => 0.66666666666667 [14] => 1.75 [15] => 0.57142857142857 [16] => 1.5 [17] => 0.66666666666667 [18] => 1.75 [19] => 0.14285714285714 [20] => 15 [21] => 2.3333333333333 )
```

What can I do to replace the NaN and INF values to ) or anything or make it an exception.

Comment: you could use a ternary: `$growthrate[] = ($arr[$i-1] !== 0) ? $arr[$i]/$arr[$i-1] : 0;`

Comment: As I see you just need to add check `if ($arr[$i - 1] !== 0)` and move `error_reporting` out of loop

Comment: `Division by Zero` is not defined. You always need to check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your problem right, just check if the divisor is not 0.

```
<?php

$arr = [1,2,0,0,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,5,7,6,4,7,4,6,4,7,1,15,35];

$growthrate = [];
for($i=1;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
    $growthrate[] = $arr[$i-1] ? $arr[$i] / $arr[$i-1] : -1; // -1 or whatever value you want...
}

print_r($growthrate);
```